# Replacing 1GBe with 10GBe NIC Failover Cluster Host

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, failover, windows-cluster

We have a 3-node Failover Cluster - all currently running 4 Port 1GBe NIC Cards. We intend to upgrade these NICs to `2x 10GBe + 2x 1GBe` NIC cards which have the following configuration:

```
Ports    1  --  2  -- 3 -- 4
Speed    10GBe 10GBe 1GBe 1GBe
```

This means we will need to reconfigure the Virtual switches as we want these to go over the 10GBe ports and currently on the existing NICs they are mapped to NIC 2 and NIC 3. Do you need to evict the host from the cluster in order to do this?

Secondly - as this will be a gradual process - do Window clusters care if each host uses a physically different NIC port relative to other hosts - for example, Host 1 uses Port 1 and 2 as VM Switches, and on Host 2 (on the old 1GBe NIC Cards) uses Port 2 and 3 etc. And say Host 1 uses Port 4 for Cluster Communication but on Host 2 it uses Port 3. Surely as long as the IP connectivity is in place and the Virtual Switches have the same names throughout the hosts, it will all work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to evict the host from the cluster in order to do this? - No.

Do Windows clusters care if each host uses a physically different NIC port relative to other hosts? - No.